# Makeindex, different kinds of references and collation in the index

Tags: makeindex

In reference to the question asked last week on how to deal with different kinds of index-entries:
[Makeindex and different kinds of references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361227/makeindex-and-different-kind-of-references/361235#361235)

I wondered if it is possible to up the ante. Again this is the section of Makeindex i'm referring to:

> In some indexes, certain page numbers are specially formatted—for example, an italic page number may indicate the primary reference, and an n after a page number may denote that the item appears in a footnote on that page.

Only that I want to show only references to notes if no primary reference is on that page. If there is a primary reference and a note-reference on the same page everybody using the index will be satisfied with the primary one, so no need for repetition.

The output of (using egregs solution from last week):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeindex 

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\nn}{m}
 {
  % split the argument at commas
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_martin_nn_in_seq { , } { #1 }
  % add a trailing n to each item
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_martin_nn_out_seq \l_martin_nn_in_seq { ##1n }
  % output the items separated, if necessary, by "comma space"
  \seq_use:Nn \l_martin_nn_out_seq {,~}
 }
\seq_new:N \l_martin_nn_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l_martin_nn_out_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document} 

bla\index{Lahm} blablab\index{Lahm|nn}

bla\index{A} bla\index{A|nn}

bla\index{B} bla\index{B|nn}

\newpage

bla\index{Lahm|nn} blablab

bla\index{B|nn}

\newpage

bla\index{B|nn}

\printindex 

\end{document}
```

should not be:

> A 1, 1n
>
> B 1–3n
>
> Lahm 1, 1n, 2n

though:

> A 1
>
> B 1–3n
>
> Lahm 1, 2n

Is that even possible?

Comment: I suspect you probably got multiple encap warnings from `makeindex`. Are you happy to try `xindy` instead?

Comment: I certainly would.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that `makeindex` can't deal with conflicting encaps (the location formatting command) for the same location. For example, page (location) 1 has an empty encap (from `\index{Lahm}`) and the encap `nn` (from `\index{Lahm|nn}`). Since `makeindex` doesn't know how to resolve this, it adds both `1` and `\nn{1}` to the location list for `Lahm` and issues a warning in the transcript. Assuming the file is called `test.tex`, then the transcript file is `test.ilg` and contains three such warnings:

```
Generating output file test.ind....
## Warning (input = test.idx, line = 4; output = test.ind, line = 3):
   -- Conflicting entries: multiple encaps for the same page under same key.

## Warning (input = test.idx, line = 6; output = test.ind, line = 7):
   -- Conflicting entries: multiple encaps for the same page under same key.

## Warning (input = test.idx, line = 2; output = test.ind, line = 11):
   -- Conflicting entries: multiple encaps for the same page under same key.
done (13 lines written, 3 warnings).
```

There's no easy way to fix this with `makeindex` other than to process `test.idx` after the `latex` call and before the `makeindex` call using some form of script. (The `makeglossaries` perl script that comes with the `glossaries` package does this if it detects `makeindex`'s multiple encap warning.)

The simplest solution is to switch to `xindy`, which resolves this conflict by giving preference to the formatting command (encap value) according to its position in the list of defined attributes. There are two attributes in your MWE: `default` (the default used when the `|` part is omitted from `\index`) and `nn`. These need to be defined in a `xindy` module (`.xdy` file). For example:

```
(define-attributes (( "default" "nn" )))
```

This gives the default attribute a higher priority. Alternatively:

```
(define-attributes (( "nn" "default" )))
```

This gives the `nn` attribute a higher priority. Unfortunately, `texindy` (the usual method of calling `xindy` when used with packages like `makeidx`) defines "default" in the `latex-loc-fmts.xdy` module, so both the above will cause the warning:

```
Loading module "latex-loc-fmts.xdy"...
WARNING: ignoring redefinition of attribute "default" in
(DEFINE-ATTRIBUTES (("default" "textbf" "textit" "hyperpage")))
```

However, if we make sure the custom `.xdy` module is loaded first, that will ensure the custom attribute list takes precedence.

There is another problem here. In the case of the `B` in your example, the `\index{B|nn}` entry will be discarded in favour of the `\index{B}` entry on page 1 when the `default` attribute overrides the `nn` attribute. This means that the location list for `B` will end up as `1, \nn{2}, \nn{3}` (since  `\nn{1}` has been discarded it can't form a range with `\nn{2}` and `\nn{3}`). This can be fixed with a merge rule:

```
(merge-to "default" "nn" :drop)
```

You also need to tell `xindy` what to do with the `nn` attribute:

```
(markup-locref :open "\nn{" :close "}" :attr "nn")
```

This just encapsulates the location with `\nn` (which is what `makeindex` does automatically). The default attribute doesn't need any special formatting.

Finally, the location list separators need to be defined. For example, to approximately replicate `makeindex`:

```
(markup-locref-list :sep ", ")
(markup-range :sep "--")
```

However, there's a difference between `makeindex` and `xindy` ranges where there is an encap value. With `makeindex`, your MWE encapsulates the range (for example, `\nn{1--3}`) whereas `xindy` encapsulates the range elements instead (for example, `\nn{1}--\nn{3}`). Similarly for consecutive encaps (for example, `\nn{1, 2}` with `makeindex` vs `\nn{1}, \nn{2}` for `xindy`). This means that the range will end up appearing as `1n--3n` with `xindy` rather than `1--3n`.  Since the `\nn` command now just encapsulates a single location, the definition is much simpler:

```
\newcommand{\nn}[1]{#1n}
```

but the range formation needs adjusting to prevent the `n` prefix from being applied to the starting location.

One way to get around it is to modify the range separator so that instead of simply separating ranges with `--` it uses a formatting command `\range{`*start*`}{`*end*`}`:

```
(markup-range :open "\range{" :sep "}{" :close "}")
```

This will change `\nn{1}--\nn{3}` to `\range{\nn{1}}{\nn{3}}`. Now `\range` can be defined to locally alter `\nn` within the scope of the start value:

```
\newcommand{\range}[2]{{\def\nn##1{##1}#1}--#2}
```

Here's the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{makeidx}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xdy}
; list of allowed attributes

(define-attributes (( "default" "nn" )))

; define format to use for locations

(markup-locref :open "\nn{" :close "}" :attr "nn")

; location list separators

(markup-locref-list :sep ", ")
(markup-range :open "\range{" :sep "}{" :close "}")

(merge-to "default" "nn" :drop)

\end{filecontents*}

\makeindex 

\newcommand{\nn}[1]{#1n}

\newcommand{\range}[2]{{\def\nn##1{##1}#1}--#2}

\begin{document} 

bla\index{Lahm} blablab\index{Lahm|nn}

bla\index{A} bla\index{A|nn}

bla\index{B} bla\index{B|nn}

\newpage

bla\index{Lahm|nn} blablab

bla\index{B|nn}

\newpage

bla\index{B|nn}

\printindex 
\end{document}
```

Assuming this file is called `test.tex` then the build process is:

```
pdflatex test
xindy -M test -M texindy -C utf8 -L english -t test.ilg test.idx
pdflatex test
```

Alternatively (since you're using `ngerman`):

```
pdflatex test
xindy -M test -M texindy -C din5007-utf8 -L german -t test.ilg test.idx
pdflatex test
```

Note that the order of the `-M` switches is important. This ensures that the attribute list in `test.xdy` comes before the attribute list in the `texindy` modules. (However, this only matters if you need to change the precedence of the attributes defined by the `texindy` modules.)

[image: image of index]

> **Index**
>
> **A**
>
> A, 1
>
> **B**
>
> B, 1–3n
>
> **L**
>
> Lahm, 1, 2n

You can remove the letter group headings by adding the following to your document:

```
\newcommand*\lettergroup[1]{}
```

If you need any more encaps, you can just add them to the list of defined attributes, so to add `ii` from your comment:

```
(define-attributes (( "default" "nn" "ii")))
```

(This makes the default and `nn` encaps override `ii`.) You don't even need to define `\ii` (although you still can if you like). For example:

```
(markup-locref :open "\emph{" :close "}" :attr "ii")
```

(which just uses `\emph` directly) or

```
(markup-locref :open "\ii{" :close "}" :attr "ii")
```

(which uses `\ii`).

Comment: wonderful! i hoped this wouldn't happen and I could move on from there myself but i'm already stuck on the next step. in fact i have three different kind of index entries, within the text direct ones and italic ones for implicit references (my command is \newcommand{\ii}{\emph{#1} ) and index entries in notes. is it possible to implement this?

Comment: @MartinMueller Yes, just add the extra encap values to the list in `define-attributes` and provide a corresponding `markup-locref` line. I've edited my answer with the code for your `ii` encap.

Comment: thank you! i made it that far but the "drop"-part does not work: if I add: (merge-to "default" "ii" :drop) and try it on this example: \index{person|ii}Person
\newpage
\index{person}\index{person|nn}\index{person|ii}Person
\newpage
\index{person}\index{person|nn}\index{person|ii}Person it ends up with three pages in italics.

Comment: @MartinMueller How about `(merge-to "nn" "ii" :drop)` instead?

Comment: Incredible job! It works!

Comment: @MartinMueller That's great :-)

Comment: I'm sorry to keep going on! But when I try to apply it to my actual book I have to use to indices. Unfortunately when I change to: \usepackage[makeindex, protected]{splitidx}
and create: \newindex[persons and works]{pw} and run splitindex and xindy the drop does not work anymore, most likely because of splitindex and it's errors of multiple encaps. is this a tiny problem or should I move to a new question?

Comment: @MartinMueller I think it might be best to post that as a new question as then it's more likely to reach someone with a better knowledge of `splitidx`.

Comment: I did: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362606/xindy-splitindex-and-attributes

Comment: I wish running `xindy` was as easy as running `makeglossaries` :-).