# xindy, splitindex and attributes

Tags: xindy

@Nicola-Talbot managed to solve my last question:
[Makeindex, different kinds of references and collation in the index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361852/makeindex-different-kinds-of-references-and-collation-in-the-index/362293#362293)

Unfortunately I don't succeed to carry this solution beyond splitindex.

This was the premise:
Consider an index with three different attributes, default, ii (implicit) and nn:

> Shakespeare\index{Shakespeare}
>
> famous playwright from Stratford\index{Shakespeare|ii}
>
> note: William Shakespeare
> (/ˈʃeɪkspɪər/;[1] 26 April 1564 (baptised) – 23 April 1616)[nb 1] was
> an English poet, playwright, and actor, widely regarded as the
> greatest writer in the English language and the world's pre-eminent
> dramatist.\index{Shakespeare|nn}

If there are entries of the default type on a page the ones with attributes should be omitted from the output.

This MWE works:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{makeidx}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xdy}
; list of allowed attributes

(define-attributes (( "default" "ii" "nn" )))

; define format to use for locations

(markup-locref :open "\emph{" :close "}" :attr "ii")
(markup-locref :open "\nn{" :close "}" :attr "nn")

; location list separators

(markup-locref-list :sep ", ")
(markup-range :open "\range{" :sep "}{" :close "}")

(merge-to "nn" "ii" :drop)    
\end{filecontents*}

\makeindex 

\newcommand{\nn}[1]{#1n}

\newcommand{\range}[2]{{\def\nn##1{##1}#1}--#2}

\begin{document} 

bla\index{Lahm} blablab\index{Lahm|nn}

bla\index{A} bla\index{A|nn}

bla\index{B} bla\index{B|nn}

\newpage

bla\index{Lahm|nn} blablab

bla\index{B|nn}

\newpage

bla\index{B|nn}

\printindex 
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately when I introduce splitindex (I have two indices), the MWE doesn't properly omit the attributes anymore:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
  \usepackage[makeindex, protected]{splitidx}
\newindex[persons]{pw}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xdy}
; list of allowed attributes

(define-attributes (( "default" "ii" "nn" )))

; define format to use for locations

(markup-locref :open "\ii{" :close "}" :attr "ii")
(markup-locref :open "\nn{" :close "}" :attr "nn")

; location list separators

(markup-locref-list :sep ", ")
(markup-range :open "\range{" :sep "}{" :close "}")

(merge-to "nn" "ii" :drop)    
\end{filecontents*}

\makeindex 

\newcommand{\nn}[1]{#1n}
\newcommand{\ii}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\newcommand{\range}[2]{{\def\nn##1{##1}#1}--#2}

\begin{document} 

bla\sindex[pw]{Lahm} blablab\sindex[pw]{Lahm|nn}

bla\sindex[pw]{A} bla\sindex[pw]{A|nn}

bla\sindex[pw]{B} bla\sindex[pw]{B|nn}
bla\sindex[pw]{B} bla\sindex[pw]{B|ii}
\newpage

bla\sindex[pw]{Lahm|nn} blablab

bla\sindex[pw]{B|nn}

\newpage

bla\sindex[pw]{B|nn}

\printindex[pw] 
\end{document}
```

I believe it has something to do with splitindex as the .ilg brings up the same warnings as makeindex:

```
Generating output file ./indextest-pw.ind....
## Warning (input = ./indextest-pw.idx, line = 4; output = ./indextest-pw.ind, line = 3):
   -- Conflicting entries: multiple encaps for the same page under same key.

## Warning (input = ./indextest-pw.idx, line = 8; output = ./indextest-pw.ind, line = 7):
   -- Conflicting entries: multiple encaps for the same page under same key.

## Warning (input = ./indextest-pw.idx, line = 6; output = ./indextest-pw.ind, line = 7):
   -- Conflicting entries: multiple encaps for the same page under same key.

## Warning (input = ./indextest-pw.idx, line = 2; output = ./indextest-pw.ind, line = 11):
   -- Conflicting entries: multiple encaps for the same page under same key.
```

Any idea how to solve this? Or should is there another way to have two indices with xindy?

Comment: What should the output be? Or what output do you get and what's wrong with it? I've compiled your example, but I'm really not sure what is meant to be wrong with it.

Comment: For example, I get `Lahm, 1, 2n` so it has omitted `1n` because there's a `1` already, but included a `2n` because there's no `2` otherwise. Isn't that what you'd expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the following from when I compile your MWE:

[image: split index with omitted entries]

This seems to be what I'd expect. For example, `Laum` is indexed multiple times on page 1, but only the occurrence without attributes is included, whereas it is only indexed once on page 2, so that occurrence is included, with its attribute.

Adapting the command line from Nicola's answer, you would use

```
splitindex -m "xindy -M test -M texindy -C utf8 -L english" test
```

if `test.tex` is the name of your file. Adapt the options you pass `xindy` for German or whatever you need as you do when not using the split index.

Comment: I can't check until tomorrow but it's very likely that my mistake was in not adapting the splitindex command to xindy.

Comment: Yes, it definitely was my mistake of using the splitindex-command without any options, i.e. with makeindex.

Comment: @MartinMueller Glad you solved it. I would have thought you'd get errors in that case, rather than just wrong output.